# To what does 身体的反应能力 refer here?

Tags: meaning

I have this text. I do not understand to what 身体的反应能力is referring. I must be missing something. What is it? Is there a clue in this text?

If you argue with you partner, you may be angry, but what has that got to do with a 'bodily reaction'? Is  the woman referring, in a subtle Chinese way, to: 'No sex after an argument'？

生活中，夫妻之间免不了因为一些事情而争吵。但有研究表明，和爱人争吵半个小时，起码要花一天的时间来恢复身体的反应能力。对于那些经常争吵一个半小时的夫妻来说，恢复的时间还要加倍。有些社会学家做过实验，实验结果表明：需要用五件积极的事情，才能消除掉一件负面事情产生的阴影。

Edit: I changed this a bit for clarity:

和爱人争吵半个小时（的人），（这些人）起码要花一天的时间来恢复（他们）身体的反应能力。
People who quarrel for half an hour with their loved ones need at least a whole day to restore/recover [不知道] 身体的反应能力 ??normal relations??

Comment: Your body's capacity to do what? To which capacity are you referring? If you argue, unless you use weapons or blows, your body is not affected. Which capacity was degraded and must recover?

Comment: the body's (including brain etc.) responsiveness (capacity to respond (correctly) to the outside world (fellow humans etc), which seems to be essential for normal life), half an hour of quarrel is bound to affect one's body's responsiveness after which one's body requires time to recover this essential function

Comment: In anger, our adrenaline levels will be higher. Our reactions will be heightened, our body's responsiveness to stimuli increased, not degraded. You mind may be in turmoil, but your body can function normally and perform necessary tasks, albeit angrily. I ask again: what bodily response must recover?

Comment: Maybe this user does not understand the text, or the stated viewpoint may be wrong 很可能本用户是不理解该文字的意思，也可能陈述的看法是错误的，this may not be a language question, 该问题很可能不是提及语言的

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better translated as neural response than literally 'bodily reaction' since the neural system controls the reaction of the body.

I'm not a neurologist, but I do have that feeling that if I had a quarrel with someone, I would need some time to restore my spirits, In that period, my reaction to outside circumstance slows down a lot, I'm distressed, distracted and thus can't focus, perhaps some nervous substances not working as usual?

You can imagine that if you quarrel with you GF, even someone throw something at you you wouldn't care that much or you couldn't even feel that.

Answer (score 1):

I'll do a rough translation of the whole text for those who don't understand.

In life, the husband and wife will inevitably quarrel over certain things (事情). However, studies have shown that arguing with your loved ones for half an hour, requires at least a whole day to **recover (恢复身体的反应能力)**. For those who often argue for an hour and a half, the time for things to **go back to normal (恢复)** multiplies. Some sociologists have conducted an experiment, showing: You need 5 positive events (事情) to cancel out one negative event (事情).

Answering OP's question, what does 身体的反应能力 mean? In the hospital, when we take care of patients, we usually refer to it as taking care of a patient's 身、心、靈 (body, mind, soul) The body refers to the physical body. Mind as in emotional state of mind, and soul is for religious purposes (whether it's Christianity, Buddhism, Taoism, etc. I took the 身体的反应能力 as more of the body and the mind combined together, some will say the emotional state of mind corresponds to the physical state of the body. I didn't find anything sexually suggestive in that paragraph.

Hope this helps.

Comment: For further explanation of 身、心、靈. The hospital system in Taiwan focuses on a patient's 身、心、靈. The medical doctor takes care of the patient's physical body. Some patient's have mental break downs and need a counselor, psychologist, social worker to assist with the emotional side of being sick. And finally, there is the religious side, for patients who have terminal stage cancer, etc, and need help not from physical medication nor from emotional support. They need spiritual support.

Comment: Thanks, I did not translate the text because I found it easy, but unclear. Is it really clear to you? I thought maybe it is just not well written.

Comment: I originally thought it was some silly written news article (the types you see in news nowadays where journalist take on the role of researchers and explain their findings) and I tried to look it up with no avail. But then I tried again and I found that the source is from HSK6 practice test. Definitely had a chuckle.

Comment: As far as grammer goes, yes, it's pretty clear and straight forward, typical of what one would see in the news papers, it is HSK 6 afterall, I wouldn't expect any less. As for "substance" in what they wrote, I think that's subjective, I personally brush these types of articles off. Now going back to academics, yes, it is important to expose yourself to different topics. Topics such as psychology and health, will be written in a different manner compared to topics such as art, etc. Good luck.

Comment: And yes, I think they could have written it better, and left out the 恢复身体的反应能力, or maybe just replaced it with something more specific as  情緒上恢复 (recovery of emotional state)